# Exclude unit testing while building gradle

Tags: eclipse, gradle

How to exclude running test cases of an application while running the build.gradle file in eclipse?

I am facing an exception for test failed. So not able to create war to build.

Comment: Well, that's not that bad ;)

Comment: How? What is the procedure for it?

Comment: I think you should fix the tests before building war file. I you don't want to go that way try: `gradle clean war -X test`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically the test should be fixed before building a war file. If this is not the way You'd like to go, try:

```
gradle clean war -X test
```

Comment: In Eclipse, add "-x test" to the Program Arguments in the Run Configuration, using Buildship.